# Looping a function, unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, function, loops, timer

Im wondering what is wrong with this for loop here. I'm trying to make a Pomodoro Study Timer, a study technique that suggests that you break down studying into 25-minute chunks that are followed by 3-5 minute breaks. here I have 2 timers that run in sequence, one after the other. When the first timer reaches zero, the second one starts. For now, i have timers set to 5 seconds and 3 seconds respectively in order to make testing quicker. It all works fine until I put the whole thing into a for loop which then brings some unexpected behaviour. I want to loop the entire function based on user input which informs the code on how many times to loop the counters(this isnt setup yet).
The timers are started by pressing a button on an html page. The button executes the pomo() function at the bottom, which contains a loop that should loop the start() function.
PS, I'm a total ultra noob so apologies if this is just terrible code, I'm really new to this :)

```
var time25 = 5;
var time5 = 3;
var timeElapsed25 = 0;
var timeElapsed5 = 0; // initializes time elapsed to zero
var time = document.getElementsByClassName("header"); //links to html
time[0].innerHTML = time25; // sets output to html

function convertToMin(s) {

  mins = Math.floor(s / 60);
  let minsStr = mins.toString();
  if (minsStr.length === 1) {
    mins = '0' + mins;
  }
  sec = s % 60;
  let secStr = sec.toString();
  if (secStr.length === 1) {
    sec = '0' + sec;
  }
  return mins + ':' + sec;
}

function start() {
  var timer25 = setInterval(counter25, 1000);
  console.log("timer1");

  function counter25() {
    timeElapsed25++
    time[0].innerHTML = convertToMin(time25 - timeElapsed25);

    if (timeElapsed25 === time25) {
      console.log("timer2")
      clearInterval(timer25);
      timeElapsed25 = 0;

      var timer5 = setInterval(counter5, 1000);

      function counter5() { //Counter For 5 minute break
        timeElapsed5++;

        time[0].innerHTML = convertToMin(time5 - timeElapsed5);
        if (timeElapsed5 === time5) {
          clearInterval(timer5);
          timeElapsed5 = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function pomo() {
  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    start();
  }
}
```

Comment: `setInterval` is asynchronous. `start()` doesn't wait for all the timers to complete, it returns as soon as it starts the timer.

Comment: i see, so how would i make it so the loop iterates only at the very end of the start() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call `start()` in a loop. `setInterval()` doesn't wait for the the countdown to complete, it returns immediately, so you're starting all 3 timers at the same time.

What you should do is call `start()` again when both timers complete. To put a limit on the number of repetitions, use a `count` parameter, and decrement it each time you call again.

```
var time25 = 5;
var time5 = 3;
var timeElapsed25 = 0;
var timeElapsed5 = 0; // initializes time elapsed to zero
var time = document.getElementsByClassName("header"); //links to html
time[0].innerHTML = time25; // sets output to html

function pomo() {
  start(3);
}

function start(count) {
  if (count == 0) { // reached the limit
    return;
  }
  var timer25 = setInterval(counter25, 1000);
  console.log("timer1");

  function counter25() {
    timeElapsed25++
    time[0].innerHTML = convertToMin(time25 - timeElapsed25);

    if (timeElapsed25 === time25) {
      console.log("timer2")
      clearInterval(timer25);
      timeElapsed25 = 0;

      var timer5 = setInterval(counter5, 1000);

      function counter5() { //Counter For 5 minute break
        timeElapsed5++;

        time[0].innerHTML = convertToMin(time5 - timeElapsed5);
        if (timeElapsed5 === time5) {
          clearInterval(timer5);
          timeElapsed5 = 0;
          start(count - 1); // Start the next full iteration

        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function convertToMin(s) {

  mins = Math.floor(s / 60);
  let minsStr = mins.toString();
  if (minsStr.length === 1) {
    mins = '0' + mins;
  }
  sec = s % 60;
  let secStr = sec.toString();
  if (secStr.length === 1) {
    sec = '0' + sec;
  }
  return mins + ':' + sec;
}
```

Comment: I see, so I'd be calling the function within itself for the number of times specified by the count parameter at which point the return statement stops the function itself.